# How does Bootstrap convert class in Javascript with babel without using @babel/plugin-transform-classes

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, babeljs

Bootstrap is using classes here : 
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/src/button.js#L51

It doesn't seem that they are using plugin-transform-classes

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/package.json#L109-L115

I noticed they are using rollup though, but I don't think that is what is causing class to convert to es5 properly.

Any ideas how they are achieving this?